# JSON.parse issue with redux state

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, redux

Using React and Redux, I'm making the call `getNoteById` which returns some string inside of `note`.

I want to JSON.parse the `note` variable but if it's undefined then setValue to `initialValue` where I know it will parse properly.

The issue I'm having is when I check to see if `JSON.parse(note)` is undefined or not, I always get the same error of undefined index at 0.

Not sure how to fix this. When the component loads and `getNotesById()` is called, `notes` or `initialValue` should be displayed when i call `setValue`.

```
const TextEditor = ({ note, getNoteById, clearValues }) => {
  const paramId = match.params.notes;
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getNoteById(paramId);

    if (JSON.parse(note) == undefined) {
      setValue(initialValue);
    } else {
      setValue(JSON.parse(note));
    }

    return () => {
      clearValues();
    };
  }, [paramId, value]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {value} </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your effect has missing dependencies: clearValues, getNoteById and note. You should skip the setValue to initialValue and do `const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);` because an effect runs **after** the render and note will be undefined on first render. Check if note is undefined with `if(note!==undefined){setValue(JSON.parse(note))}`.

Your code should look something like this:

```
const TextEditor = ({ note, getNoteById, clearValues }) => {
  const paramId = match.params.notes;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    getNoteById(paramId);

    if(note!==undefined) {
      setValue(JSON.parse(note));
    }

    return () => {
      clearValues();
    };
  }, [clearValues, getNoteById, note, paramId, value]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {value} </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My guess is that you don't want to dispatch getNoteById again when the note is loaded and set in the redux state. Maybe create 2 effects:

```
const TextEditor = ({ note, getNoteById, clearValues }) => {
  const paramId = match.params.notes;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  //dispatch getNoteById when param id changes
  useEffect(() => {
    getNoteById(paramId);
    return () => {
      //dispatch a cleanup action
      clearValues();
    };
  }, [clearValues, getNoteById, paramId]);
  //set the note to it's parsed json when it changes
  //  and is not undefined
  useEffect(() => {
    if (note !== undefined) {
      setValue(JSON.parse(note));
    }
  }, [note]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {value} </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the approached is what I asked for, however what about that split second where I see the initial value?

Comment: @jackstride I think this is why react is creating [suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html). I assume the `note` comes from a fetch request and you don't know how short or long it will take, you could render `loading` instead but that will still flash by when the fetch is quick.